# Angular lookup value/display value

Tags: angularjs

I have some data on a model that comes in the form of a code such as "US60" and "US70".

I need to take that value and show a display value such as "US 7day/60hour" and "US 8day/70hour". I'm not sure if there is any best practices way to do this in Angular, and I'm not having much luck googling it.

What I would do is have a service that I pass in type and value, and it would return a display value, but as with many things in Angular, since this is my first Angular project, I don't know if it's a good way to do it or not.

I'm just needing to use the display value in html such as `{{settings.cycle}}` I am already able to access the variable, but I want to show the display value, not the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting the gist of your question correctly, you have the value available but want to alter how it is displayed on screen right?

There are two main approaches to do this in Angular, using a directive or a filter.

A [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter) is basically like a pipe in Unix. You can alter a value before it is being displayed. For example:
`{ username | uppercase }` will transform the username into an all-caps username. Naturally, you can define your own filters for your use case. Filters are mostly used to transform single values. So for your case, a filter sounds best.

A [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) is commonly used to create entire components on a page. For example: `<user-profile-card></user-profile-card>` would be transformed, using the directive, into the appropriate html/css/logic. So these are used often for larger transformations which involve logic, like server requests. Still these directives could also be used for very small components.

So for your case, although what you are actually want to do is not completely clear to me honestly, a filter seems to be your best shot ;)